# How to handle large may html/js files?

Tags: javascript, html, large-files

I am working on HTML/JS based reports that *should* consist of one file.  The current report is therefore 500 kB but this works quite well.  However when you want to see the source code in Chrome it may freeze.  A new report I am working on contains even more data and is currently around 1.5 MB.  It is more or less impossible to see the source code in Chrome and I am afraid that it could cause trouble on slow devices.

Any advise?  Best practices?  I have googled and searched through Stackoverflow but I couldn't find anything about size limits or about html/js code layout suggestions for easier Browser digestion.  (I know from other languages, C++ for instance, that there exists hints how to make large files better digestable for the compiler, resulting in much faster compilations.)

Edit: The current report's code size is by 99% HTML. (Tables)  The tables are afterwards beautified with [Datatables](http://datatables.net).  Removing all JS code unfortunately makes no difference.  By the way, I have experimented with removing whitespaces (1.5 MB -> 1.1 MB) and also loading data from array instead of storing them in hard-coded html `table`, `tr`, `td` elements (1.5 MB -> 1.6 MB) but performance characteristics did not change.

It's static files and the problem also occurs locally.

2nd edit: I converted now the rest of the hardcoded table content to JS arrays and removed white-spaces, reducing size further.  Now the file is at 900 kB and loads significantly better, the freezes are now for only about 3-5 seconds.

Comment: Try making less of a mess. You should separate content from code. Try using XML to store the content in an structured way, JavaScript to retrieve and manipulate it, and HTML and CSS to display it, and keep this in separate, smaller files, so when you ask for the source code it's code you're actually viewing, and it's presented in a compact and rational way.

Comment: Yes, but I would dislike this solution.  The nice thing about the current solution is: like a PDF, Word or Excel Report, you can E-Mail, store and backup it as one self-contained file.  In contrast to PDF it is absolutely platform independent, in fact it even works with text browsers.

Comment: I see. Maybe consolidation in a self contained file should be your last step after development. You can try to automate the process so you can deliver and read the report as one file but also break it into its parts and put it together again when necessary for source editing purposes. It may not be worth the extra work at the beginning if you're not making many changes, but anyways working on a 1.5MB text file of everything just doesn't seem a good developing approach to me....

Comment: The report is of course dynamically generated, so the templates are pretty well readable. But for debugging I need to use `curl`. However I'm picking up your idea with splitting: I'll generate an online version (multiple files) and an easy download version (one file). That should do the trick.

Comment: I managed to squeeze down the size to 300 kB doing some simple dictionary-based compression.  Now everything is good.  Anyways, I still wonder whether it is basically impossible to reasonably deal with HTMLs > 1 MB.

Answer (score 0):

Viewing the source code in Chrome should not cause it to freeze. Does the page render fast or slowly? If it is the latter it maybe a sign of rogue JavaScript running. Can you post any of the code for us to see?  Also, what web server are you using? You can try and reduce the page size by using something like `GZip Compression` or `JSCompress`.

http://jscompress.com/

Comment: Neither JS nor CSS are usually part of the html page source so compressing them won't affect the source viewer.

Comment: @ThiefMaster - this would be depend if the javascript/css is embedded on the page.  The OP hasn't provided code so I am assuming they have put it all in one file, as he states `should consist of one file`

Comment: All, Thanks for your suggestions.  The page renders decently fast.  Could be faster but it's fine.  The problem also occurs w/o any JS code, see edited question.

Comment: Darren, I will try to store the data as JS array and then compress it.  (Unfortunately this adds an external dependency, UglifyJS+node in case of jscompress)